# Post HTML5 video playlist to facebook

Tags: facebook, html5-video, share, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am trying to post two videos in single playlist without using any flash player. I have tried following code.

```
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Test" />
   <meta property="og:url" content="LINKING_URL" />
   <meta property="og:title" content="test!!!!" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="preview_image_url" />
   <meta property="og:type" content="video.tv_show" />

   <meta property="og:video:url" content="http://mydomain/video1.mp4" />
   <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://mydomain/video1.mp4" />
   <meta property="og:video:url" content="http://mydomain/video2.mp4" />
   <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://mydomain/video2.mp4" />
   <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
   <meta property="og:video:width" content="480" />
   <meta property="og:video:height" content="360" />
```

By applying this, First video is displaying on my FB wall and its playing also.

Actually I need to add two videos in single post video but its adding only one.

I have tried with `video.episode, video.other, video.movie`. But there is no successful result.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: It is not possible. You need to use Flash

Comment: @WizKid but its not compulsory that every user's system installed with flash player. So thats what i am trying to use HTML5 player.

Comment: There is no way to use HTML5. Either flash or just specify one video